# UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet. in jframe

Tags: java, swing, hibernate, jframe

I am making an application in jframe using Hibernate. When I try to jump from Login page to sign up button (`onButtonAction`), Java throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
at librarymanage2.UserSignUp.<init>(UserSignUp.java:34)
at librarymanage2.LoginPage.jButton3ActionPerformed(LoginPage.java:209)
```

I used this code to jump:-

```
UserSignUp n=new UserSignUp(this);
n.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
n.setVisible(true);`
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 2):

This means that the constructor of your `UserSignUp` class (somehow) throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`, either by itself or via a method call.

If you want more help than this, then post more code.

Also, open the `UserSignUp` class in your IDE's decompiler to see what's happening at around line 34. Well it should be the line that throws `UnsupportedOperationException`. See the code right before that, and if there are some conditions leading up to that point. In particular, the `this` parameter you're passing to the constructor, perhaps there are some checks on it, and as a result the class decides that the operation on this object is not supported and so it throws.